# How to create a data table in web page using spreadsheet and appscript

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a source dump in google trix like below:

Name    Month   quantity
Apple   Jan     10
Banana  Feb     15
Orrange Jan     50
Grapes  Mar     5

and i need to get summary in webpage using spreadsheet and appscript as given below.

Month   Quantity
Jan     60
Feb     15
Mar     5

Can any one please help on this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're getting your data as a csv file.  Then this should work.

```
function monthlyTotals(fileId) {
  var fileId=fileId||"default file id";//update your fileId 
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');//update your sheet name
  sh.clear();
  var file=DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  var csv=file.getBlob().getDataAsString()
  var dA=Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  var mObj={fA:['Month'],'Month':'Quantity'};//Stuck in my own titles here
  dA.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(i>0) {//skipped the first line assuming it is a header line
      if(!mObj.hasOwnProperty(r[1])) {
        mObj[r[1]]=Number(r[2]);
        mObj.fA.push(r[1]);
      }else{
        mObj[r[1]]+=Number(r[2]);
      }  
    }          
  });
  mObj.fA.forEach(function(f,i){
    sh.appendRow([f,mObj[f]])
  });
}
```

If you want the headers from the data:

```
function monthlyTotals(fileId) {
  var fileId=fileId||"default fileId";
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh.clear();
  var file=DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  var csv=file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var dA=Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  var mObj={fA:[]};
  dA.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(i>0) {
      if(!mObj.hasOwnProperty(r[1])) {
        mObj[r[1]]=Number(r[2]);
        mObj.fA.push(r[1]);
      }else{
        mObj[r[1]]+=Number(r[2]);
      }  
    }else{
      mObj[r[1]]=r[2];
      mObj.fA.push(r[1]);
    }
  });
  mObj.fA.forEach(function(f,i){
    sh.appendRow([f,mObj[f]])
  });
}
```

Comment: Is there any posibility to get through webpage using html instead of csv??

Comment: I have to have more details to accomplish that. I need to know exactly how the data is structured on the website.